# Based on selected option on one page hide input on another page in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i have this view Index :

```
    <h1>Přidání nové reklamy do systému</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="row">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @area = "Home", @role = "form" }))
                {


                        <!-- Select Basic -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="typ_reklamy">Typ reklamy</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select id="fnivel" name="typ_reklamy" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="1">Reklama na určitou částku</option>
                                    <option value="2">Reklama na určitou dobu</option>
                                    <option style="display:none;" value="3">Reklama na určitý počet kliknutí</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                }


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And when i select this option in selecet:

```
 <option value="1">Reklama na určitou částku</option>
```

I need on this page :

```
   <h1>Přidání nové reklamy do systému</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="row">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @area = "Home", @role = "form" }))
                {
                    <fieldset>


                        <div class="form-group" id="fnivel2" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="datumz">Datum začátku</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    <input id="textinput" readonly name="datumz" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.datumz" class="form-control input-md" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="fnivel3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="datumk">Datum konce</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    <input id="textinput" readonly name="datumk" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.datumk" class="form-control input-md" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </fieldset>

                }


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hide this two inputs:

```
<div class="form-group" id="fnivel2" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="datumz">Datum začátku</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    <input id="textinput" readonly name="datumz" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.datumz" class="form-control input-md" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="fnivel3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="datumk">Datum konce</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    <input id="textinput" readonly name="datumk" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.datumk" class="form-control input-md" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

But i don´t know how to accomplish this in mvc.

Problem is how to pass value of option from view index to view detail.

Please can you help me ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use onchange="postvalues()" event and post values and catch in action
JavaScript function 

         function postvalues()
         {
                  $.ajax({ url: '/home/Detail', 

                    type: 'POST', 

                    data: { optionvalue: $("#fnivel").val() }, 

                    dataType: 'json', 

                    success: success 

             });
           }



    In controller 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Detail(string optionvalue)
    {
      ViewBag.Optionvalue=optionvalue
     return View();
     }
```

Comment: When i debug my code in controller this variable optionvalue is null and i also dont´know how to hide the inputs in my detail view because when i have this: <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

  
        if (optionvalue === '1') {
                $('#fnivel2').removeAttr('pk').hide();
                $("#fnivel3").removeAttr('pk').hide();
            }
    });

</script> in my view detail the vartiable optionvalue is unknow